# Spot the error in $\int\frac{dx}{x\ln x\sqrt{\ln^2x+2\ln x + 4}}$

Tags: integration, substitution, hyperbolic-functions

Please don't answer with other integration strategies, I'm trying to understand my error. Thanks.

I'm trying to integrate this

$$\int\frac{dx}{x\ln x\sqrt{\ln^2x+2\ln x + 4}}.$$

My try: letting $\ln x=y$, we have that $\frac{dx}{x}=dy$ so

$$\int\frac{dx}{x\ln x\sqrt{\ln^2x+2\ln x + 4}}=\int\frac{dy}{y\sqrt{y^2+2y+4}}=\int\frac{dy}{y\sqrt{\left(y+1\right)^2+3}}.$$

Now let $y+1=\sqrt3\sinh z,$ so $dy=\sqrt3 \cosh z \ dz$:

$$\int\frac{dy}{y\sqrt{\left(y+1\right)^2+3}}=\int\frac{\sqrt3 \cosh z}{(\sqrt3\sinh z-1)\sqrt{3\sinh^2 z +3}}dz=\int\frac{dz}{\sqrt3\sinh z -1}=$$

$$=\int\frac{dz}{\sqrt3\left(\frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{2}\right)-1}=2\int\frac{dz}{\sqrt3(e^z-e^{-z})-2}=2\int\frac{e^z}{\sqrt3e^{2z}-2e^z-\sqrt3}dz.$$

Let $e^z=t,$ so $e^z\ dz=dt$:

$$2\int\frac{e^z}{\sqrt3e^{2z}-2e^z-\sqrt3}dz=2\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt3t^2-2t-\sqrt3}=2\int\frac{dt}{\left(t-\sqrt3\right)\left(t+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\right)}=$$

$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt3+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}}\int\left(\frac{1}{t-\sqrt3}-\frac{1}{t+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}}\right)dt=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\ln \left|\frac{t-\sqrt3}{t+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}}\right|+c.$$

Recalling the substitution we have that

$$\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\ln \left|\frac{t-\sqrt3}{t+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}}\right|+c=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\ln \left|\frac{e^{\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{\ln x+1}{\sqrt3}\right)}-\sqrt3}{e^{\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{\ln x+1}{\sqrt3}\right)}+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}}\right|+c$$

for all $c\in \mathbb{R}$, but according to [integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com) this isn't a correct antiderivative. Can someone spot the error please? I can't find it out.

Comment: If the antiderivative is this complicated, it might be that what the calculator gave is equivalent to yours but looks very different. The only way to tell is to check very carefully. Or stick them both in a graphing program and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a factor in this step:
$$2\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt3t^2-2t-\sqrt3}=2\int\frac{dt}{\left(t-\sqrt3\right)\left(t+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\right)}.$$  Expanding in the denominator yields $$t^2 + \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} - \sqrt{3}\right)t - 1.$$  This was the first error I found, after which I did not continue to check.

Comment: You're definitely right. Now the antiderivative is correct, it was just there. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In the last line (before the words "Recalling..." should be

$$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{1}{t-\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{t+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\right)$$

Anyway my result is $$\frac{1}{2} \left[\log \log x-\log \left(2 \sqrt{\log ^2x+2 \log x+4}+\log x+4\right)\right]+C$$